# Best way to get list of folders in .NET and then search for particular names?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io

I am using C# with ASP.NET 4.5.

Let's say I have a folder called "accounts" which contains a folder for each user account in my system. So folders that exist in accounts may be "companyabc", "companyxyz", "companyzzz".

I also have a listing of account names as an array of strings (ListOfAccounts).

I'm trying to write a piece of code that will look at each account name in ListOfAccounts and see if there is a corresponding folder with the same name in the "accounts" folder.

One way to do this like this:
foreach accountname in ListOfAccounts {
     check to see if the folder "/whatever/accounts/{accountname}" exists
     do something if it doesn't
  }

However I am concerned about performance because there may be a large number of accounts, and asking .NET to check for each folder one at a time seems like it is not very efficient.

Instead I would like to do something like this:
   get list of all directory names in the "accounts" folder (DirectoryList)
   foreach accountname in ListOfAccounts {
      check to see if the accountname is in DirectoryList
      do something if it isn't
   }

So I am trying to figure out the most direct and efficient way to do this.

I see I can use DirectoryInfo and .GetDirectories, but this returns a DirectoryInfo[] and I am not sure how to best search it.  I can do this:

```
DirectoryInfo di = New DirectoryInfo("\path");
DirectoryInfo[] dirArray = di.GetDirectories();

foreach (string accountname in AccountList) {
  foreach (DirectoryInfo dirinfo in dirArray) {
    if (accountname = dirinfo.Name)
       found = true;
       break;
    }
  }
  if (found == false) {
     // accountname not in list of directories
     do something
  }
}
```

That looks terribly inefficient!

So my next thought was to loop through the dirinfo and build a hashtable.  And then foreach through the accountnames and see if it is in the hashtable one by one.  That seems a lot more efficient.

However I keep thinking there must be a much better, easier and or more efficient way to go about this.  Like if I could just do a query directly somehow like this:

```
 foreach (string account in AccountList)
  {
     if (dirarray.SearchSomehow(account))
       // found
  }
```

What do you guys think? Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be 100's of directories. Loading everything and check for required one is inefficient.

Usually these kind of things are done for only the required directories.

```
foreach (string account in AccountList)
{
    DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(baseDir,account));
    if(info.Exists)
    {
       //Do your work here
    }
}
```

Not sure am missing something.

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between this approach and the one given by pravprab? That approach looks like its more direct and less code, but not sure if that makes it better...?

Comment: @user2838966 That's technically correct and same as this except you shouldn't use `"//"` to generate path because in various operating systems path seperators may change, so I used  `Path.Combine` which will handle those things OS friendly. Simply if he used `Path.Combine` instead of `path + "//" + account` both are same

Answer (score 0):

You can check directory exists or not by

```
foreach (string account in AccountList)
{
    if(Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(path,account) )) 
   // found
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. This looks like the easiest and most direct way to do it. My concern, however, is that calling Directory.Exists hundreds (or eventually thousands) of times in a loop like this may be slower or inefficient - compared to getting all the directory names at once in a list. Then enumerating through those names. What do you guys think?

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel Thanks for suggesting `Path.Combine` instead of `path + "//" + account`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a LinqPad script that I used to stub this out.  I did this LinqPad script since a lot of times when I have had to process something similar then a lot of times the reverse direction eventually comes up.  It's a pattern I have just continued to do when have 2 lists that may or may not match and need to take action for any number of item states.

```
void Main()
{
    var AccountList = new List<string>();
    AccountList.Add("account1");
    AccountList.Add("account2");
    AccountList.Add("account3");
    string accountsPath = @"c:\accounts";

    //Initialize Account List Dictionary object.
    var accountsDictionary = AccountList.ToDictionary(a => a, a => AccountStatusEnum.Unprocesed);

    //check for account directory existance.
    AccountList.ForEach(account => {
        if(Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(accountsPath,account))) {
            accountsDictionary[account] = AccountStatusEnum.AccountFolderExists;
        }
        else {
            accountsDictionary[account] = AccountStatusEnum.AccountFolderDoesNotExists;
        }
    });

    //check for directories without account
    Directory.GetDirectories(accountsPath)
            .Select(d => Path.GetFileName(d))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(item => {
                if(!accountsDictionary.ContainsKey(item)){
                    accountsDictionary.Add(item, AccountStatusEnum.NoAccountForFolder);
                }
            });

    accountsDictionary.Dump();

    //Process as necessary for each status.
    ProcessAccountList(accountsDictionary, AccountStatusEnum.AccountFolderExists);      
    ProcessAccountList(accountsDictionary, AccountStatusEnum.AccountFolderDoesNotExists);
    ProcessAccountList(accountsDictionary, AccountStatusEnum.NoAccountForFolder);
}
public void ProcessAccountList(Dictionary<string,AccountStatusEnum> accountsDictionary, AccountStatusEnum accountStatus)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\r\n"+accountStatus.ToString());
    accountsDictionary
        .Where(item => item.Value == accountStatus)
        .Select(item => item.Key)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(account => {
            //what to do for each status.
            switch (accountStatus) {
                case AccountStatusEnum.AccountFolderExists:
                break;
                case AccountStatusEnum.AccountFolderDoesNotExists:
                break;
                case AccountStatusEnum.NoAccountForFolder:
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }

            account.Dump();
        }); 
}

public enum AccountStatusEnum {
    Unprocesed = 0,
    AccountFolderExists,
    AccountFolderDoesNotExists,
    NoAccountForFolder, 
}
```

Results:

```
//accountsDictionary.Dump();
account1    AccountFolderDoesNotExists
account2    AccountFolderExists
account3    AccountFolderDoesNotExists
account4    NoAccountForFolder

//query results of false values
AccountFolderExists
account2

AccountFolderDoesNotExists
account1
account3

NoAccountForFolder
account4
```

Hope this helps.